# How to plot accuracy bars for each feature of an array

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have a data set "x" and its label vector "y". I want to plot the accuracy for each attribute (for each column of "x") after applying NaiveBayes and cross-validation. I want a bar graph.
So at the end I need to have 3 bars, because "x" has 3 columns. And the classification has to run 3 times. 3 different accuracies for each feature.

Whenever I execute my code it shows:
     ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1 3]
     DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and willraise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import cross_validation
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
    clf = GaussianNB()

    x = np.array([[0, 0.51, 0.00101], [3, 0.54, 0.00105], [6, 0.57, 0.00108], [9, 0.60, 0.00111], [1, 0.73, 0.00114], [5, 0.76, 0.00117], [8, 0.89, 120]])
    y = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])

   scores = list()
   scores_std = list()
   for i in range(x.shape[1]): 
   xA=x[:, i]
   scoresKF2 = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, xA, y, cv=2)
   scores.append(np.mean(scoresKF2))
   scores_std.append(np.std(scoresKF2))
   plt.bar(x[:,i], scores)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the shape of your input data, `xA`, shows us that it is 1-dimensional -- specifically, it is `(7,)` shape. As the warning tells us, you are not allowed to pass in a 1d array here.  The key to solving this in the warning that was returned *Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample*.  Therefore, since it is just a single feature, do this `xA = x[:,i].reshape(-1, 1)` instead of `xA = x[:,i]`.

I think there is another issue with the plotting.  I'm not completely sure what you are expecting to see but you should probably replace `plt.bar(x[:,i], scores)` with `plt.bar(i, np.mean(scoresKF2))`.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I changed both values as you told me and now it works.